# How do I find an E.E. to partner with for a product?

Tags: iphone, interface, mac

I am a software developer and need to work with a partner who will design and develop a device (SIMPLE device) to interface with the iPhone hardware port.  I am not sure of the best place to find such a person.

This would be a part-time thing - it won't take much to develop it.

I already have the Apple hardware spec (through the Apple program) and now just need someone willing to design this.

Answer (score 8):

You could approach a local University's, electronics (or electrical engineering or computing) department to see if they might have some reasonably competent students who might be interested in a part time project of this nature (think hands on work experience which pays). Depending on the nature of the project you might also be able to partner up with the uni to offer it as a project to students for some aspect of their course.

Just my tuppence worth.

Amos

Comment: I would +1 vote this if I had the reputation.  I agree - the first place I thought of was a local university.  I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 7):

You're going to need more than just an EE.  You'll need someone who's experienced at packaging electronics (housing, connectors, etc NOT cardboard boxes and plastic blister packs), and someone who can shepard a device through the FCC approval process.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest doing this with an electrical department at a university or with a company. Work out a deal for IP first (ie. talk about the reward you want for your time), and if it is a good project, the university will normally take over the FCC and patenting process.

This means less money for you if it is a good product, as you share rights, but the university effectively acts as an investor, giving the money required for the process and in return expecting some profit.

You will need a larger university, although I cannot be specific on what size as this type of thing varies with location, but if you are in Oklahoma I can get you in contact with a professor for OSU.

Hope it helps.
-Max

Comment: Even at a smaller University you may be able to find students looking for experience who can do part of the job for you, we used to get offers of employment for both monetary and experiential rewards all the time, passed on by the head of the course (this was for programmers/web designers usually as that was the nature of my course).

Comment: I would agree, if all you really want is a partner, talk to professors and find out if they can get you in contact with anyone. Please be cautious though, I have met a good share of incompetent students that professors like.

Like all things, professional experience can mean alot.